# How do you fix "adb locksettings not found"?

Tags: 7.0-nougat

I have a J3 Eclipse running Android 7.0 plugged into my computer and try to view the locksettings by typing `adb shell locksettings`. This returns `/system/bin/sh: locksettings: not found`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried updating the phone to Android 8.1 and 9.0 and the issue seems to have been solved in both releases. If you're facing this issue try updating the OS and see if the problem still persists.